# How to prevent floating editor windows in eclipse 4 RCP apps?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

Eclipse 4 RCP apps support floating editor windows.

Using the compatibility layer, I am porting a set of RCP apps from Eclipse 3.8 to Eclipse 4.4. These applications have not been designed for floating editors. I would like to defer the cost of re-design until later.

The [Eclipse enhancement request for floating editor windows](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8886), in comment 40, mentions the desirability of controlling policy for editor windows:

> In e4 we'd ideally be able to 'host' what is currently either an editor or a view anywhere in the layout. The choice of limiting its location to an editor area should be enforced through some 'policy'.
>
> Note that it's not really that simple, mostly due to the ingrained differences in how the Menu/TB are handled for editors (i.e. any place hosting an editor would -require- a 'main' toolbar to host the editors tools.

Questions:

- How can I turn off the ability to float editor windows?
- Can I do that in a way that still allows editor windows to be dragged between workbench windows?
- Alternatively, if we allow floating editor windows, is there an easy way to make an existing ActionBarAdvisor be used for a newly dropped editor, to set up its menu and toolbar?

Comment: If you leave the DndAddon out of the application model then you stop windows being dragged anywhere.

Comment: I would like to retain the 3.x ability to drag views out of the workbench window.

Comment: You could try to: a) Create an AddOn which listens for the creation of floating windows and always moves the part back into its former stack b) extend/manipulate the DndAddon to block floating windows

Comment: Looks like `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DetachedDropAgent` is responsible for this, but I can't see a way to control it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution, but it's not pretty, and there are a few gotchas.

This solution requires copying the entire package of the Eclipse DnDAddon, and making a small change within DetachedDropAgent. (After @greg-449's initial comment and some initial research, I had hoped to replace DndAddon with my own class that installed a subclass of DnDManager. However,  DnDManager and other critical classes are package-protected.)

This working idea comes from Eric Moffat, the development lead for Eclipse e4, in a response to my enhancement request [Disabling floating editors](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=437213). He lists two other options there, one of which is similar to @christoph.keimel's option *a*.

Below are some details. This works with at least Eclipse 4.4.

First, you need an application model file. If you don't already have one, extract the file `LegacyIDE.e4xmi` from the Eclipse plug-in *org.eclipse.ui.workbench*.jar*. Copy it to your own plug-in with a new name (in this example, *myApp.e4xmi*). Then cause it to be used by adding a property `applicationXMI` to the product extension in your application's plugin.xml file.

```
   <extension
         id="product"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            application="com.mycompany.myapp"
            name="MyApplicationName">
         ...
         <property
               name="applicationXMI"
               value="com.my.plugin/myApp.e4xmi">
         </property>
      </product>
   </extension>
```

Next, copy the entire package `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon` from the plug-in *org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt*.jar* into your own package `*.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon`.

That suffix of that package name is important. It's also important not to change the name of the add-on class `DnDAddon`. If you change either, you'll find that the standard DnDAddOn gets added in addition to your modified one, thanks to `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt.DnDProcessor`, and editors may still be floated.

Next, in *myApp.e4xmi*, modify the "DnD Addon" line to point towards your version. The contributionURI includes the name of the plug-in containing your version of DnDAddon, and the class path to it. For example:

> <addons xmi:id="_bqcWME2EEd-DfN2vYY4Lew" elementId="DnD Addon" 
>          contributionURI="bundleclass://com.one.of.my.plugins/com.mypackage.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDAddon"/>

Finally, in your DetachedDropAgent class, modify the canDrop() method to fail for compatibility editors. (I wrote the added code below.)

```
public class DetachedDropAgent extends DropAgent {
...
@Override
public boolean canDrop(MUIElement dragElement, DnDInfo info) {
    if (info.curElement != null)
        return false;

    // Add this code to disable floating of editors using the compatibility layer.
    String elementId = dragElement.getElementId();
    if ( "org.eclipse.e4.ui.compatibility.editor".equals( elementId )) {
        return false;
    }

            ...
}
```